# Cannot resolve Android Support Library

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

After updating Android Studio the Android Design Library is resolved but the Android Support Library is not resolved.

[image]

**Gradle File**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

I am using Android Studio 2.1.2

**Edit**

This is wierd as both v4 and v7 versions of the support libraries are included in dependencies of design library

```
\--- com.android.support:design:23.3.0                                                         
     +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
     |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.3.0
     |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0
     |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0
     |    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.3.0
     |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0
          +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0 (*)
          \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0
```

**Update**

When I ran command '***gradew app:dependencies***' to get project dependencies, Android Studio downloaded a lot of '.pom' files before showing the results.

```
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle-2.1.2.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.1.2/gradle-core-2.1.2.pom     
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/2.1.2/builder-2.1.2.pom             
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/25.1.2/lint-25.1.2.pom                  
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/2.1.2/gradle-api-2.1.2.pom       
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compilerCommon/2.1.2/compilerCommon-2.1.2.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/2.1.2/builder-model-2.1.2.pom 
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/2.1.2/builder-test-api-2.1.2.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdklib/25.1.2/sdklib-25.1.2.pom                   
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdk-common/25.1.2/sdk-common-25.1.2.pom           
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.1.2/common-25.1.2.pom                   
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/25.1.2/manifest-merger-25.1.2.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/25.1.2/ddmlib-25.1.2.pom              
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/25.1.2/lint-checks-25.1.2.pom    
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/annotations/25.1.2/annotations-25.1.2.pom         
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.1.2/baseLibrary-2.1.2.pom     
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/25.1.2/layoutlib-api-25.1.2.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/25.1.2/dvlib-25.1.2.pom                     
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/repository/25.1.2/repository-25.1.2.pom           
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/25.1.2/lint-api-25.1.2.pom
```

But after that the issue got resolved, and build succeeded with the existing gradle file.

Can anybody throw some light on what might have occurred in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Follow two steps:

**1. At first update your Support library from SDK manager:**

[image]

**2. Add the following dependencies in your Build gradle:**

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0"
```

Comment: Both support v4 and v7 libraries are included in dependencies of design library.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upadate Android Support Library on SDK manager to latest revision.